# CollectionView -Stop/Prevent Section Header from Scrolling Beyond a Certain Point

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

I have a collectionView that is pinned to the top of the view controller with a no navigationBar `collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true`.

It has a sticky header `let headerLayout = cv.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout; headerLayout?.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true`

The collectionView has 2 sections, the first section has no header but the second section does have a header. The issue is because the collectionView isn't pinned to the safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor and there isn't a navigationBar, when I scroll, the header in the second section gets pinned to the very top of the screen behind the status bar.

How can I prevent the header from scrolling beyond a certain point. For example if I had a button pinned to the top of the screen, the header would stop once it hit the bottom of the button

```
myButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never

    let secondIndexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 1)

    collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
    if let headerFrameInCollectionView = collectionView.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryElement(ofKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, at: secondIndexPath), let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: \.isKeyWindow) {

        let headerFrameInSuperView = collectionView.convert(headerFrameInCollectionView.frame, to: collectionView.superview)
        let headerOriginY = headerFrameInSuperView.origin.y

        let buttonFrame = view.convert(myButton.frame, to: window)

        let bottomOfButton = buttonFrame.origin.y + buttonFrame.height

        if headerOriginY == bottomOfButton {

            collectionView.contentInset.top = headerOriginY // stop header from scrolling any further

        } else {

            collectionView.contentInset.top = 0
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, to get this to work I had to set the `collectionView.contentInset.top` to whatever point I wanted section two's header to stop at but I also had to set the `collectionView.contentOffset.y` to a stop position.

```
if headerOriginY <= bottomOfButton {

    collectionView.contentInset.top = bottomOfButton

    collectionView.contentOffset.y = cellHeightFromSectionOne - bottomOfButton

} else {

    collectionView.contentInset.top = 0
}
```

In long, I have 2 sections and what happens is if I set `collectionView.contentInset.top = bottomOfButton` in section 2 without changing the `collectionView.contentOffset.y`, the cell in section 1 scrolls off the screen and the whole process is very buggy. To get it to work:

1- get the height for the cell in the first section. Luckily for me this was easy because in section 1 the cell's height is the width of the screen and there is only 1 cell in section 1. In section 2 there aren't any cells so the cell size for that is `.zero`:

```
// size for the cells
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width // the collectionView is the same width

    if indexPath.section == 0 {

        return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
    }

    return .zero // section 2 has no cells, just a header
}
```

2- In `scrollViewDidScroll`, this is where all the work is done. The variable names explains the process

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never

    let secondIndexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 1)

    collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()

    if let headerTwoAttributes = collectionView.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryElement(ofKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, at: secondIndexPath), let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: \.isKeyWindow) {

        let headerTwoFrameInSuperView = collectionView.convert(headerTwoAttributes.frame, to: collectionView.superview)

        let headerTwoOriginY = headerTwoFrameInSuperView.origin.y

        let buttonFrame = view.convert(myButton.frame, to: window)

        let bottomPositionOfButtonInWindow = buttonFrame.origin.y + buttonFrame.height

        let stopScrollingPositionY = bottomPositionOfButtonInWindow

        let cellHeightFromSectionOne = UIScreen.main.bounds.width

        let preventFirstCellInSectionOneFromScrollingPosition = cellHeightFromSectionOne - stopScrollingPositionY

        if headerTwoOriginY <= stopScrollingPositionY {

            collectionView.contentInset.top = stopScrollingPositionY
                    
            collectionView.contentOffset.y = preventFirstCellInSectionOneFromScrollingPosition

        } else {

            collectionView.contentInset.top = 0 // reset this to 0
        }
    }
}
```